# How to get last 2 digits of year from Javascript date

Tags: javascript, string, date, formatting, format

I have string in the following format "30.11.2019". I need to transform it into a Date and get the short year representation (last 2 digits from year) like "19".
The following code doesn't work

```
var strDate = new Date("30.11.2019");
var shortYear = strDate.getFullYear();
```

Comment: simple modulo 100 operation

Answer (score 10):

new Date() does not work with a single string argument in that format.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Easiest way is to call it with 3 arguments (year, month, day).
Do note that `month` is the month index (0 based), so November (11th month) is actually 10th in the format that Date expects.

```
  new Date(2019, 10, 30).getFullYear() % 100;
  // returns 19;
```

If you can't do it this way and you simply must work around the string format mentioned, then you can just do

```
const dateString = '30.11.2019';
const year = dateString.substring(dateString.length-2);
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm not entirely sure if you want only short representation of the year or whole date, BUT with short representation of the year on it - if so, then I would suggest using `toLocaleDateString` method:

```
new Date(2019, 10, 30).toLocaleDateString('pl', {day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: '2-digit'})
```

It will return you:

```
"30.11.19"
```

or if you want to get the short year date only:

```
new Date(2019, 10, 30).toLocaleDateString('en', {year: '2-digit'})
```

it will return you:

```
"19"
```

Comment: +1 for using .toLocaleDateString()
this is what it was built for.

Answer (score 3):

You can get last two digits with the following code:

```
var strDate = new Date(); // By default Date empty constructor give you Date.now
var shortYear = strDate.getFullYear(); 
// Add this line
var twoDigitYear = shortYear.toString().substr(-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the string you're using isn't in a format recognized by `Date.parse()` (more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)), you need to manually create that Date object.

For example:

```js
const strDate = '30.11.2019';
let [d,m,y] = strDate.split(/\D/);
const date = new Date(y, --m, d);

console.log(date.getFullYear())
```

You can then use `Date.getFullYear()` to get the year and extract the last two digits, as you need.

Comment: @RobG that is so much more elegant! Updating the answer accordingly :)

Comment: Why do you need --m in `new Date(y, --m, d)`?

Comment: @ndrewl the second argument to Date() is an integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December. Since the numeric representation of the month in the original string begins with 1 for January, we need to reduce it by `1` before we pass it to Date(). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I'm currently learning JavaScript, and it seemed a bit unnatural to me that days start at 1, but months at 0. If someone else is interested, here is the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

```
var strDate = "30.11.2019";
var lastdigit = strDate.slice(-2);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

do not need split string, I think.
using [moment](https://momentjs.com)

`yarn add moment`

```
const moment = require( 'moment' );

const simpleYear = moment( "30.11.2019", "DD.MM.YYYY" ).format( "YY" );
console.log( "simpleYear = " + simpleYear );
```